# Oracle Unique Record Retrival

Tags: oracle

Having below three tables as described:

```
SELECT * FROM Users;

UserID    UserName
1          Ramesh
2          Suresh


SELECT * FROM UserAddress;

UserAddressID    UserID     Address   
1                  1          South St
2                  1          North St
3                  2          New St

SELECT * FROM UserDegree;

UserDegreeID      UserID      Degree
1                  1            BSC
2                  2            B.Tech
3                  2            M.Tech
```

I need output like given below,

```
UserID  UserName  UserAddressID   UserID   Address  UserDegreeID  UserID  Degree
1        Ramesh     1               1     South St    1            1       BSC
NULL      NULL      2               1     North St    NULL         NULL    NULL
2        Suresh     3               2     New St      2            2      B.Tech
NULL      NULL      NULL           NULL   NULL        3            2      M.Tech
```

Can anyone help me to get this output without using any looping?

Comment: Guys please copy and past my posted details in any one editor to see the content with better readability

Comment: If UserID is matched then still why you don't want to print the UserID/UserName at row-2 of your output, is it really required or you missed that??

Comment: Sorry vivek i missed it. The UserID and UserName can be present in row 2 and row 4 also

Comment: Can you re-update your expected output, there are many NULLS which confuses.

Comment: UserID  UserName  UserAddressID   Address  UserDegreeID  Degree
1        Ramesh     1              South St    1          BSC
1        Ramesh     2              North St    NULL       NULL
2        Suresh     3              New St      2          B.Tech
2        Suresh     NULL           NULL        3          M.Tech

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL that is joined on all of your three tables, check out hopefully resolve your issue.

```
select  u.userid,
    u.username,
    a.useraddressid,
    a.userid as userid2,
    a.address,
    d.userdegreeid,
    d.userid as userid3,
    d.degree
from users u
     join useraddress a on (u.userid = a.userid)
     join userdegree d on (u.userid = d.userid);
```

Here, Joining the SQL on "UserID" field so, don't need to select "userid" from all of the tables, it will the same records. So, whereever you want to use this "userid" you can refer the same "userid" in application". In below SQL, I removed the "userid" that is repeated.

```
select  u.userid,
    u.username,
    a.useraddressid,
    a.address,
    d.userdegreeid,
    d.degree
from users u
     join useraddress a on (u.userid = a.userid)
     join userdegree d on (u.userid = d.userid);
```

Comment: Not getting the output as expected